# Python - List/matrix concatenation/combination

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, matrix, product

I've got 2 list/matrices

```
a = [[1,   2,  3],
     [4,   5,  6],
     [7,   8,  9]]

b = [[10,  11,  12],
     [13,  14,  15],
     [16,  17,  18]]
```

and I want to get result like

```
result = 
[[(1, 10), (1, 11), (1, 12), (2, 10), (2, 11), (2, 12), (3, 10), (3, 11), (3, 12)], 
 [(4, 13), (4, 14), (4, 15), (5, 13), (5, 14), (5, 15), (6, 13), (6, 14), (6, 15)], 
 [(7, 16), (7, 17), (7, 18), (8, 16), (8, 17), (8, 18), (9, 16), (9, 17), (9, 18)]]
```

what to do in python?? plz help

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What exactly was the problem?

Comment: what have you tried ? what is the relation between a b and result ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not a correct way to write a list in python. I also took the liberty to assume each row was a list. So that **a** and **b** are lists of list.

```
a = [
[1,   2,  3],
[4,   5,  6],
[7,   8,  9]
]

b= [
[10,  11,  12],
[13,  14,  15],
[16,  17,  18]
]

result = []
for ix, i in enumerate(a):
    temp = []
    for j in i:
        for k in b[ix]:
            temp.append((j,k))
    result.append(temp)

print(result)
```

> [[(1, 10), (1, 11), (1, 12), (2, 10), (2, 11), (2, 12), (3, 10), (3,
>   11), (3, 12)], 
>  [(4, 13), (4, 14), (4, 15), (5, 13), (5, 14), (5, 15),
>   (6, 13), (6, 14), (6, 15)], 
>  [(7, 16), (7, 17), (7, 18), (8, 16), (8,
>   17), (8, 18), (9, 16), (9, 17), (9, 18)]]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools.product` for this:

```
from itertools import product

a = [[1,   2,  3],
     [4,   5,  6],
     [7,   8,  9]]

b = [[10,  11,  12],
     [13,  14,  15],
     [16,  17,  18]]

res = [list(product(a[i], b[i])) for i in range(len(a))]
```

Result:

```
[[(1, 10), (1, 11), (1, 12), (2, 10), (2, 11), (2, 12), (3, 10), (3, 11), (3, 12)], 
 [(4, 13), (4, 14), (4, 15), (5, 13), (5, 14), (5, 15), (6, 13), (6, 14), (6, 15)], 
 [(7, 16), (7, 17), (7, 18), (8, 16), (8, 17), (8, 18), (9, 16), (9, 17), (9, 18)]]
```